# Arrays - square-free word

Tags: java, arrays, char

This is what the program should do:

***The word, zatabracabrac, is not square free, since it has subword, abrac twice start-
ing at position 4 of the word.***

We are not allowed to use *strings*, *breaks* or other complex stuff. I get the square and square not part but am unable to find its place. I think I went wrong some place like I can't figure it out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  // part (a) of the main

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("***************************");
  System.out.println("        Part (a)");
  System.out.println("***************************");

  do{
    System.out.println("Enter a word and then press enter:");
    String str=keyboard.next();
    char[] word = str.toCharArray();

    isSquareFree(word);
    System.out.println("Do you want to test another word? Press y for yes, or another key for no");

  }while(keyboard.next().charAt(0)=='y');

public static void isSquareFree(char[] word){
  int z = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<word.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<word.length-1;j++){
        if (word[j] == word[j+1]){
            z = 1;
            j = word.length;
        }
        else{
            z = 2;
        }
      }
    }
    if (z == 1){
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Not Square Free");
    }
    else{
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Square Free");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does `aba` has a square `a` at 1 and 3? Does `aab` has a square `a` at 1 and 2?

Comment: no it's square free ... here an e.g ana is square-free  ....................
borborygmus is not square free, since it has subword, bor twice in in a row.

Comment: but yea aab has a square at 1

Answer (score 1):

*Downvotes on the question: this is not where you solve your homework... we all went through having homeworks and solved them (well, most of us), and that's partly why we're capable of helping you.*

You're checking whether the `word` contains two consecutive characters which are the same.
That's not what you want, try another solution.

Here's why it does what I said above:

- The outer `for` loop doesn't have an effect on the inner one, since `i` is not used inside
- Index `j` and `j+1` in the same iteration as a character and the next one

Other notes:

- `j = word.length` is the same as `break` here, try using that, it stops your loop like the end condition was satisfied; read more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html
- For easier testing, you might want to use another `main` function containing only calls like `isSquareFree("zatabracabrac".toCharArray());`, even multiple ones to see multiple test results at once
  This will greatly reduce the change-compile-run-check cycle's length.
- You can use a debugger in an IDE (Eclipse or IntelliJ) to see what your program does.
- Without debugging you can use `println/print/printf` calls to see how many iterations you have and what your values during those iterations.

Hints on solution:

- As I see you're essentially looking for consecutive k-length subword duplicates
- You phrased it right in the comment, the arbitrary length is giving it `another level`
- At each position `i` try to look for a subword with length `k` which has a corresponding match starting at `i + k` (this helps the consecutive constraint)
- `k` can be anything between a letter and half of the string (more than that is overkill since it cannot repeat twice)
- I didn't code it, but it would be my first try

In your examples:

```
borborygmus
^=>
i
borborygmus
   ^=>
   i+k
With k = 3 there is a match
```

```
zatabracabrac
   ^===>
   i
zatabracabrac
        ^===>
        i+k
With k = 5 there is a match
```

Comment: I tried to help by giving you where you may have missed something, as well as I thought you may wonder why the down-votes... see update.

Comment: k thnx. so ...to find subword where am i going to put the k ..like u confuse me again now ... u r saying inside the loop of j right

Comment: `k` is arbitrary, you have to try each possible one. Try fixing it to `3` first (`int k = 3;` outside the loops) and make it give a good result for `borborygmus` and `bopborygmus`. And then add another loop around your working code.